# "We found an issue in the following area(s): Title" in google play console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I can't understand how to fix the app rejected problems, after rename the app Name then also it shows the same problem.
can anyone help me out of this problem.

[image]

Comment: Care to share your application's title so we can understand where the issue is?

Comment: "Mii WhatsApp - easily access" this is my application name @tomerpacific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe due to Misleading text your app is rejected
[reference to google play policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9898842?hl=en#zippy=%2Cexamples-of-common-violations)